# MouseListener & MouseMotionListener don't work for JPanel with JComponents inside

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to drag JComponents which are inside a JPanel on a JFrame or better on the rootPane of the JFrame.

The JPanel which contains the components is using a horizontal BoxLayout.

When I run the code below I observed the following issues:

1. The MouseListener & MouseMotionListener are only working for the JLabel
2. The JLabel seems to be not visible
3. On trying to drag, the JPanel with the JComponents inside the JTextfield & JButton disapper once I hover over the location where the JButton was dragged it becomes visible again.

What am I doing wrong here? Such a little code and so many unexpected issues.

Please help!

Code to reproduce the issues:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class Main extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    private volatile int screenX = 0;
    private volatile int screenY = 0;
    private volatile int myX = 0;
    private volatile int myY = 0;
    private JPanel myPane;

public Main() {
    setSize(500,500);
    myPane = new JPanel();
    //myPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(myPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    JTextField tf = new JTextField("Some text");
    tf.setEnabled(false);
    tf.setSize(110,20);
    JLabel l = new JLabel("°C");
    l.setSize(40,20);
    JButton b = new JButton("Button");

    myPane.setSize(new Dimension(tf.getWidth()+l.getWidth(), tf.getHeight()));

    myPane.add(tf);
    myPane.add(l);
    myPane.add(b);
    rootPane.add(myPane);

    myPane.addMouseListener(this);
    myPane.addMouseMotionListener(this);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main f = new Main();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    screenX = e.getXOnScreen();
    screenY = e.getYOnScreen();
    myX = myPane.getX();
    myY = myPane.getY();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Entered");
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    // only move when edit mode selected
    System.out.println("Dragged");
    int deltaX = e.getXOnScreen() - screenX;
    int deltaY = e.getYOnScreen() - screenY;

    myPane.setLocation(myX + deltaX, myY + deltaY);

    revalidate();
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

}
}
```

Comment: You need to read up on how the listeners work - and while at it, read up on some design principles like "single responsibility". You're only adding the listener to the panel so it will only get executed if the panel receives the event. However, components inside the panel will get the events first if the mouse is over them and then those components might consume the event so it doesn't reach the panel's listeners at all.

Comment: Could you perhaps demonstrate how to apply your recommendationson the above example code? I think this would give me a first orientation where I can read more your mentioned points.

Comment: You might want to start by clarifying what exactly you are trying to do. Right now I'm not sure I fully understand what you're writing - maybe add some example etc. Are you trying to implement drag-and-drop and expect the panel to be draggable even while hovering the texfield and button?

Comment: Btw, you should also read up on the layout managers that Swing uses. Calling `setSize()`, `setLocation()` etc. won't work if there's a layout manager that does its own size and location calculations. You might want to take it step by step and learn about layouts, components, listeners, drag-and-drop, etc. individually and thoroughly before trying to combine them and struggling with a multitude of potential issues. - As for your request: Unfortunately I haven't used Swing in years so I'm a bit rusty on the details and I also don't have the time for lengthy debugging and demonstrations.

Comment: Thomas, thank you for your answers so far. I'm trying to drag the pane with the components inside and after moving them I want to export the new position etc.  to an XML file. Right now the dragging need only to work on the same parent pane. So I don't need to drag from one window to another or something like this. The dragging should only work when the user clicks the left mouse button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add components to the root pane. There are other components that will be added on top and cover your components.

The panel should be added to the content pane and the content pane needs to use a null layout when dragging components.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Top Level Containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html). There is also a link that goes into more detail on the root pane. As you will see the content pane covers the root pane.

You can also check out [Moving Windows](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) the **Basic Dragging** section provides a simple reusable class that can be used to drag any component so you don't need to hardcode variable names in the class.

Comment: Thank you @camickr both link were helpful and using the ComponentMover class [link](camick.com/java/source/ComponentMover.java) worked fine for me. Indeed the JTextfield is consuming the mouse events so that the events cant be received by the one level higher component in the containment hierarchy.